# Creating meaningful parameter names with Generics

Tags: .net, generics

I'm hoping there's some clever way to do this.  I have a generic base service that has several  methods... So currently there are some methods in this base class like Create(T obj).  What I'd like is for the compiler to create a more intuitive parameter name (based off of some rule) so that when a concrete instance of the base service is created like this:

```
public class ProductService : BaseService<Product>
```

I want it to compile the ProductService method to this (for example):

```
public Product Create(Product product)
```

instead of

```
public Product Create(Product obj)
```

I know it sounds minor but an intern asked me the other day and I couldn't tell him 100% sure that it wasn't possible.

Comment: I don't know of any way to accomplish what you are asking, but even using `entity` apposed to `obj` would make more sense to me reading your code. Especially if the class inherited from an `IEntity` Interface or from a base `Entity` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way of achieving this automatically. However, if you really wanted to do it anyway, you could make the method `virtual` in `BaseService`, and override it in each subclass:

```
public override Product Create(Product product) {
    return base.Create(product);
}
```

Comment: I agree that's probably the best way to achieve what the poster asked for, but that sounds like a lot of effort for a really tiny benefit.  I wouldn't advise actually doing it, but it would work.

Comment: @JonathanRupp: +1; agreed - in particular, because `Product obj` or `Product entity` still makes semantically sense.

Comment: Yeah... Sometimes there are these little subtitles that I miss on occasion... I was hoping for something like 

public void Insert(T @@T.GetType().Name.ToLower())

Moreover, with that mentality, I could compile time reflect on T... But oh well... put in a nice to have w/ the clr team I guess...